# Executing async functions one at time Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, telethon

```
api_id = apiid
api_hash = hash
client = TelegramClient('friend', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

def checkPanelAvailable(panelId):
    client.connect()
    client.send_message("Bot", "/start")
    @client.on(events.NewMessage("Bot"))
    async def handler(event):
        if event.raw_text == "Choose function":
            await event.respond("Checkpanel")
        if event.raw_text == "Enter IP:":
            await event.respond(panelId)
        if event.raw_text == "Choose command:":
            await event.respond("check connection")
            await client.disconnect() # THERE IS THE FINISH OF THE FUNCTION
    client.run_until_disconnected()

checkPanelAvailable("1.1.1.1")
checkPanelAvailable("2.2.2.2")
```

How can I launch this two functions one by one.
Launching second function when first comes to finish point

Comment: Which two functions?

Comment: `checkPanelAvailable` is a sync function, so your code should already launch them one by one. What happens when you run it?